# Number of max concurrent connections for nodejs+mongo db for simple insert operations

Tags: mongodb, tcp

Basically my objective is to compare performance/max number of connections supported by .Net/Java TCP server with MySQL database against Node tcp server with Mongo db.

I've setup a separate Windows server  2008 R2 VM with 4 GB RAM for each Node TCP server, SQL db, Mongo server, >Net TCP server.

The data that client sends is very simple (<100 bytes). The server accepts it and insert that data into the database(MySQL or Mongo).
.Net/Java TCP server --> MySQL
Node-->Mongo db.

The client creates 1000 simultaneous requests using the threads. 
I see that Node TCP server is not capable of handling more than 700 requests, around 200-300 requests are failed as connection is refused by the server. (Node TCP serve uses non blocking Mongo operation)

The .Net TCP server is able to handle up to 1500 request without fail, even it fails if more than that number.

I'm aware that max concurrent connections are decided based on many factors (hardware, OS etc).

I surprising to know that Node  claims to support 10K+ concurrent connections. But I'm not able to achieve even 1000+, I know that interacting with Mongodb may be causing this issue. But how to support 10k+ concurrent connections in such case.

Can anybody please help me in understanding this.

Thank you in advance
-Patil

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your operating system, you need to tune it for that kind of load.  Have you considered linux instead?  It's significantly more powerful and stable than Windows, and unlike Windows (which is purposefully "crippled" (low TCP default limits) to encourage upsell), Linux comes out-of-the-box ready for much higher workloads, and can also be tuned for 10x better performance than Microsoft.